# s2-quickstart command not found

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, grails, groovy

After running `grails s2-quickstart com.loginSystem User Role` I see

```
| Error Command not found s2-quickstart
```

error message

I added `spring-security-core` in dependencies on build.gradle file and compiled project successfully

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of grails you are using, I did however encounter something similar.

I was using gradle 6.8 and `implementation 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:4.0.4'`
this resulted in me getting the same error but with
`compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:4.0.4'` I was able to avoid the issue.

**further notes**:

I was able to replicate the error with a fresh grails application running 4.0.3, 4.0.10 and 4.0.13 using the default version of gradle using "implementation" rather than "compile" I suspect this is the cause. something to note as "compile" is deprecated in later versions of gradle i believe gradle 7.0 it is no longer available.